# django-rest-auth vs djoser, Which one to use for Social Authentication?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth, djoser

I am unable to understand which one is better to use between django-rest-auth and djoser.

Previously I was using django-rest-auth but it is now unmaintained. I wanted to use jwt support for authentication. I also wanted to perform Social Authentication through Facebook. But django-rest-auth uses djangorestframework-jwt, which is again unmaintained and it also did not have any support for refresh tokens.

While wandering around on internet I found out another library 'Djoser', which also does the same thing, has better jwt support(django-rest-framework-simplejwt), but lacks the support of allauth for social authentication. It does provides social authentication through the use of python-social-auth (again depricated), but it's in the beta phase.

Please suggest me Which library to use, considering I want to use both jwt and social authentication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [dj-rest-auth](https://github.com/jazzband/dj-rest-auth), is the mantained fork of django-rest-auth. It has jwt support as well as social authentication.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you to go for my fork of django-rest-auth. I added the SimpleJWT support and you can use allauth for social authentication. Atleast I'm using the same.

This is the link to the repo.

Install it using pip. The instructions are in the repo readme.

https://github.com/ankurpandeyvns/django-rest-auth

Comment: Hi Ankur , I already saw your repository before asking this question. But is it good to use django-rest-auth even if it is on pause.

Comment: It works very well with Django 2.2.x. I don't know if v3 is going to break it or not, but if it does, i'll update my repo accordingly.